# Use DataTable buttons without using DataTable

Tags: php, html, datatable

I am trying to find a way to use the DataTable buttons even on tables where I'm not using DataTables. I have a report website where some of the reports take too long to load and error out. I found that they are using up all the available memory allotted to them and then getting stuck and never finishing. I've found a way around this, but it means I can't use DataTables when the result set has more than 500 rows. Even 500 is slow, most reports have over 100 columns many with long notes or comments. So I make then regular HTML and use SQL Offset and Fetch Next to get just 150 rows at a time. When I do this I want to still use the DataTable Buttons like `Excel` to export my table.

Is there a way to use the DataTable Buttons, especially `Excel` without having the table initialized as a DataTable?

If more info is needed let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from people that are on the DataTables forums [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38655/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-buttons-with-out-having-datatables-format-the-table#latest).

Basically they said that it isn't possible to use the buttons without using the DataTable formating. So for anyone who wants to know, it can't be done.